# $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each not executing second time around

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatables

I have the following code that on second execution does not get executed even though the check boxes are checked. Please help. Thanks

Edit: I just added the code that gets what rows in the table have been checked using the checkboxes. I am sorry there is too much code to post.
Basically the second time around it does get the correct rows but the second function that itterates the checked checked boxes does not run.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() { 
            if (this.checked == true){
                var del_id = $(this).parents("tr").data();
                console.log('!del_id', del_id);
                del_arr.push(del_id.id);
                myData ={"spreadsheets_ids": del_arr};
                console.log('mydata:', myData);

            }
        });
             ///OFF TO AN AJAX CALL AND LOTS OF OTHER STUFF HAPPENS
```

Before it comes back below

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    var $tr =  $(this).closest('tr');
    var del_id = $tr.attr('data-id');
    console.log('STILL TO BE DELETED:  =' + del_arr);

    $.each(del_arr, function(index, value ) {

        console.log('EVEN STILL TO BE DELETED:  =' + del_arr);

        if (value == del_id){
            $tr.remove();
            console.log('Removing :'+  del_id +' And ' + value);
            return false;
        }
    });
})



$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() { 
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
    if (this.checked == true){
        console.log('I am still checked')
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle please.

Comment: what do you mean of `not get executed`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of this...

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
```

This is what is working now..

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
```

Comment: Can you make that in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't wrapped your `each` in the `change` event handler of `checkbox`.

```
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {

    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var del_id = $tr.attr('data-id');

        $.each(del_arr, function(index, value) {
            if (value == del_id) {
                $tr.remove();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```